# Can I use antd less variable in my component?

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

### Question

I'm using NG-ZORRO to make UI more standard.

I have a business component and I want to align the primary color with Ant Design. I saw [Theming Your Own Components](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components) in Angular Material, but I didn't find a solution for NG-ZORRO yet. When I use `@primary-color` in my components' style file(e.g. test.component.less), I got an error: `Variable @primary-color is undefined`.

How can I reference NG-ZORRO less variable in my own component?

### My Solution

I found a solution, but I am not sure it is elegant.

In component less, I imported `path/to/ng-zorro-antd/style/themes/default.less` at first line, then `border: 1px solid @primary-color` worked as well.

Is it a right way for using NG-ZORRO less variable in my component?

Comment: Are you using LESS or SCSS pre-processor for your angular project? That matters

Answer (score -1):

similar with Angular Material, You can create a custom theme in your project and use it for your component:  https://ng.ant.design/docs/customize-theme/en